# Refresh Google Business API Access Token in code

Tags: c#, google-my-business-api

I have got a basic test console app working to retrieve Reviews via the My Business API

```
https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/{parent=accounts/*/locations/*}/reviews
```

I create an Access Token by using the OAuth 2.0 Playground and enter it into the test console app. That works fine until the Access Token expires.

How can I refresh that token in code without having to involve any user interaction?

This is the basic code that I have at the moment:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Access Token");
var accessToken = Console.ReadLine();

var credentials = GoogleCredential.FromAccessToken(accessToken);

if (credentials.IsCreateScopedRequired)
{
    credentials = credentials.CreateScoped(scopes);
}

var myBusinessApiV4Service = new MyBusinessService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credentials
});
```

There is other code that calls the API and deals with the returned review data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the accessType to "offline":

https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/implement-oauth#offline-access.

Comment: Link to the Java Google API client library might help:  https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-api-client/latest/com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl#com_google_api_client_googleapis_auth_oauth2_GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl_setAccessType_java_lang_String_